# Objective-C method with completion block returns value that I want to use in the completion block

Tags: ios, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I've encountered this problem several times coding for iOS with AFNetworking but I've managed to find a workaround until now.

Basically, I want to make an API call that returns an value to the main thread that I want to then use in the completion block of the call.

More specifically, I have a post object (like posting a tweet or something) that has associated #tags and @tags that I want to POST *after* the initial "tweet" is created in my db. I need it to be in the completion block of the method because I need to use the post_id as a parameter for posting the #tags and @tags:

```
-(void)postToDB
{
    _postId = [[[ReelRailsAFNClient sharedClient] createPostWithParameters:
                                                            @{@"user_id":_userId,
                                                              @"caption":_caption}
                                            CompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                                if(!error){
                                                    [self postHashtagsToDB:_postId];
                                                    [self postAttagsToDB:_postId];
                                                 }
                                            }] postId];
    }
```

Inside the body of postHashtagsToDB and postAttagsToDB, _postId evaluates to (null). How do I capture and inject the postId into `postHashtagsToDB` and `postATtagsToDB`?

Thanks,

JA

**EDIT**:

here is my method definition for createPostWithParameters:CompletionBLock:

```
- (Post*) createPostWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
              CompletionBlock:(AFNClientErrorCompletionBlock)block{
    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];

    [self POST:@"posts" parameters:parameters
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){
            NSLog(@"Post Created Successfully");
            post = responseObject;
            block(nil);
     }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Post Not Created");
            block(error);
     }];
    return post;
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, the completion handler will call before createPostWithParameters returns any value as a result you cannot use _postId inside the completion block handler. I think, you should call postHashtagsToDB and other methods in different threads inside the completion block handler with few seconds delay which allow the createPostWithParameters to return the value. Hope it might help.

Comment: where is `_postId` declared? Is it a local variable or instance variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReelRailsAFNClient` appears to be a class you control (I literally found one result on Google -- this question). Since you control it, I suggest modifying the completion block API to supply the post ID if you expect to be able to use it within the contents of the block.

**Side note**: try not to name things that aren't classes with a leading uppercase character. `CompletionBlock` is unconventional; replace it with `completionBlock` or simply `completion`.

**Edit**: You may modify your API to be something like this:

```
typedef void (^AFNClientErrorCompletionBlock)(Post *post, NSError *error);

- (void)createPostWithParameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
          completionBlock:(AFNClientErrorCompletionBlock)block{
  Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];

  [self POST:@"posts" parameters:parameters
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Post Created Successfully");
        post = responseObject;
        block(post, nil);
   }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Post Not Created");
        block(post, error);
   }];
}
```

**Side note**: If you are returning an object (i.e. an instance of `Post`) it is a good idea to not assign it to something called `_postID`. A more appropriate assignment is `_post`.

Comment: CompletionBlock is part of the method call so it's capitalized because of camelcase convention

Comment: how would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: `createPostWithParameters` does not begin with a capital. In Apple source code, it is unconventional to begin anything that isn't a class, protocol, or category with a capital letter.

Comment: But it's not necessary to change the API. You're answering a different question.

Comment: It was marked as a side note and a comment. It's really unnecessary to point out that the asides are not directly answering the question...